# Mysql update a row if its the only matching result

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like so:

```
Item
---------
id
parentId
name
inventoryNumber
```

I need to update the inventoryNumber if and only if the row...

1. parentId = 12345
2. name string matches exactly a given string "The
   quick brown fox"
3. the row is the only row that matches the first two
   criteria.

I believe I know how to do this if I was just doing a select...

```
SELECT * FROM Item WHERE parentId=12345 
AND name LIKE 'The quick brown fox' HAVING count(*)=1
```

but I need to update the row...

`UPDATE Item SET inventoryNumber = 456 WHERE` *this is the only row where parentId=12345 and the only row where name='The quick brown fox'*

I have about 5000 of these rows to update so it would greatly reduce my workload if I can get a way to update in a single statement.  Can this be done?

**UPDATE:** I already tried putting this in a subquery like:

```
UPDATE Item SET inventoryNumber = 456 WHERE id IN (
   SELECT id 
   FROM Item 
   WHERE parentId = 12345 AND name LIKE 'The quick brown fox' HAVING count(*)=1
);
```

But I get an error from MySql when I do that "You can't specify target table 'item' for update in FROM clause:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using a `subquery`:

**EDIT**

```
CREATE TABLE Item_tmp LIKE Item;
INSERT INTO Item_tmp SELECT * FROM Item;

UPDATE Item SET inventoryNumber = 456 WHERE id IN (
   SELECT id 
   FROM Item_tmp
   WHERE parentId = 12345 AND name LIKE 'The quick brown fox' HAVING count(*)=1
);
```

Comment: I tried that and I get an error...You can't specify target table 'item' for update in FROM clause

Comment: Take a look again kasdega. I hope it solves your issue. Cheers.

Comment: My table is huge so I qualified the INSERT INTO statement and had to update the update/select statements to hit the index but other than that this solution worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Update Item set inventoryNumber = 456 where parentId=12345 and name = "The quick brown fox" group by parentId,name  having count(*) =1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [working demo on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2b96/1).

It uses this SQL query:

```
UPDATE Item SET Item.inventoryNumber = 200
WHERE  Item.id IN (
  SELECT A.id FROM (
    SELECT * FROM Item i GROUP BY i.parentId, i.name HAVING COUNT(*)=1
  ) AS A WHERE A.parentId = 12345 AND A.name = 'The quick brown fox'
)
```

Breakdown of the query:

- Innermost query: Use `GROUP BY` to select unique rows (based on your criteria #3)
- Next: Filter out rows based on your criteria #1 and #2
- Use the results in the `WHERE` clause of `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 0):

Hers is a solution that uses a CTE with a Window function to ensure uniqueness of the rows in the update source.   In this example we update the master table with ids from the student table where they match on name and DOB, but only if there is a single row in the update source.   It runs pretty quickly (2 seconds, 77K updates, 100K rows in tblMaster, 225K rows in tblStudent)

```
;WITH CTE (StudentId, Fname, Mname, LName, DOB, RowCnt)
    as (
    SELECT StudentId, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, DateOfBirth as DOB, SUM(1) OVER (Partition By FirstName, ISNULL(Left(MiddleName,1), ''), LastName, DateOfBirth) as RowCnt
    FROM tblStudent
    )
    UPDATE tblMaster
        SET ID = StudentID, MatchType = 'Exact'
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE (ID = 0 OR ID IS NULL)
      AND DateOfBirth = DOB
      AND FirstName = Fname 
      AND LastName = LName
      AND (MiddleName is Null OR Mname is Null OR Left(MiddleName, 1) = LEFT(Mname,1))
      AND RowCnt = 1
```